# How to write recursive procedures in python 2.7 correctly?

Tags: python-2.7, recursion

I have the following code in python 2.7:

```
net = {'Freda': [['Olive', 'John', 'Debra'], ['Starfleet Commander', ' Ninja Hamsters', ' Seahorse Adventures']], 'Ollie': [['Mercedes', 'Freda', 'Bryant'], ['Call of Arms', ' Dwarves and Swords', ' The Movie: The Game']], 'Debra': [['Walter', 'Levi', 'Jennie', 'Robin'], ['Seven Schemers', ' Pirates in Java Island', ' Dwarves and Swords']]}

def get_secondary_connections(network, person):
    if person in network:
        for person in network:
            connections = network[person][0]
            result = connections
            for connection in connections:
                result = result + get_secondary_connections(network, connection)
                return result
    return None        
print get_secondary_connections(net, 'Fred')
```

When I execute it gives the following error:

```
result = result + get_secondary_connections(network, connection)

RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Please tell me where I went wrong.

Comment: There's no end condition. You are sending `network` each time and hence it never ends

Comment: The code you've presented does not exhibit the problem you describe.  I'm inclined to guess that the problem in your actual code arises from having one or more loops in the relationship graph.  You need to add a way to ignore nodes you have already traversed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, pay attention to the semantics: use lists `[x, y, z]` for a collection which you're intending to loop through; use tuples `(x, y, z)` for a fixed-length collection which you're intending to index into, which is not big enough to become its own class. So you should have

```py
net = {
    'Freda': (['Olive', 'John', 'Debra'], 
              ['Starfleet Commander', ' Ninja Hamsters', ' Seahorse Adventures']), 
    'Ollie': (['Mercedes', 'Freda', 'Bryant'], 
              ['Call of Arms', ' Dwarves and Swords', ' The Movie: The Game']),
    'Debra': (['Walter', 'Levi', 'Jennie', 'Robin'], 
              ['Seven Schemers', ' Pirates in Java Island', ' Dwarves and Swords'])
}
```

Second, when doing a recursion problem, step through what you want to happen with some examples first, as if you were the machine. Your first task when processing `Freda` is to load her connections `Olive, John, Debra`. What do you want to do with each of these? Well you're going to try to load Olive's connections, fail, try to load John's connections, fail, then try to load Debra's connections, and then you'll have `Walter, Levi, Jennie, Robin.` What do you want to do with this list? Return it? Concatenate with anyone else's friends? There's nothing "recursive" about the secondary connections, at least not as one would normally think. It would in other words seem to match the name of the function to define:

```py
def get_secondary_connections(network, person):
    primary_connections, movies = network.get(person, ([], []))
    out = []
    for friend in primary_connections:
        secondary_connections, movies = network.get(person, ([], []))
        out.extend(secondary_connections)
    return out
```

No recursion needed. When do we need recursion? Well, if we wanted to find *everyone* who this person is connected to by a friend or a friend-of-a-friend or a friend-of-a-friend-of-a-friend, *then* we need to explore the whole graph and recursion might be helpful. Of course we might also want this thing to not contain duplicates, so we might want to use a `set` rather than a `list`.

A first stab might be:

```py
def get_all_connections(network, person):
    primary_connections, movies = network.get(person, ([], []))
    out = set(primary_connections) # copy this list into an output set
    for friend in primary_connections:
        out = out.union(get_all_connections(network, person))
    return out
```

And *now* you will discover that indeed, in the wrong sort of network, this thing will easily exceed a maximum recursion depth. A simple network that does this:

```py
net = {
    'Alice': (['Bob'], []),
    'Bob':  (['Alice'], [])
}
```

Why does this happen? Because to find all of Alice's friends you need to find all of Bob's friends, but to find all of Bob's friends you need to find all of Alice's friends. So how do we get past this?

We can ask for all of Bob's friends *excluding those that come through Alice*. This will need to be a full list otherwise we will just trip up on other cyclic cases, like:

```py
net = {
    'Alice': (['Bob'], []),
    'Bob':  (['Carol', 'Dylan'], []),
    'Carol':  (['Alice'], []),
    'Dylan': (['Bob'], [])
}
```

note that when we ask for Bob's friends we will recurse on both Carol and Dylan, we need to tell both of them to exclude *both* Alice and Bob, as already being handled. So that leads to

```py
def get_all_connections(network, person, excluding=()):
    if person in excluding:
        return set() # we exclude by immediately returning the empty set.
    excluding_us_too = excluding + (person,)
    primary_connections, movies = network.get(person, ([], []))
    out = set(primary_connections)
    for friend in primary_connections:
        out = out.union(get_all_connections(network, person, excluding_us_too))
    return out
```

This cycle-detection strategy is known by a few different names, but usually the tuple here is called a "path" since when we process any of Dylan's friends it says `('Dylan', 'Bob', 'Alice')`, meaning that we got to Dylan's friends by visiting first Alice and then Bob and then Dylan.

Notice that 'Carol' is nowhere in Dylan's path; this can sometimes be a good thing and sometimes not: if Dylan connects to Carol and get_all_connections applied to Carol produces a million results even when excluding Alice and Bob and Dylan, then we can expect both of these to produce the same million results for Dylan, and then when we get to Bob we have to `union` these two million results into a set of only one million -- that's a lot of unnecessary work!

So another stab would then be to keep a queue of people-to-handle and people-we've-handled. At this point you would not want so much to use recursion, you'd rather use normal looping constructs.

```py
def get_all_connections(network, person):
    visited, to_visit, out = set(), set([person]), set()
    while len(to_visit) > 0:
        visiting = to_visit.pop()
        visited.add(visiting)
        connections, movies = network.get(visiting, ([], []))
        for friend in connections:
            out.add(friend)
            if friend not in visited:
                to_visit.add(friend)
    return out
```

A loop like this can be converted into an efficient recursion, but unfortunately Python does not make this style of recursion efficient, making the exercise academic rather than practical.

Comment: Thank you, @CR Drost, for helping me :)